# How can I pass two string at a time

Tags: c++, string, class

Can anyone please fix the errors?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class base{
public:
    int i,j;
    char s[10],r[10];

    void set(char a, char b ){
        s[10]=a;
        r[10]=b;
    }

    void show()
    {
        cout<<s+std::string(r);
    }
};

int main()
{
    char a[10],c[10];
    cout<<"Enter first string"<<endl;
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"Enter second string"<<endl;
    cin>>c;
    base b;
    b.set(a,b);

    return 0;
}
```

ERROR:

> In function 'int main()': 32:14: error: no matching function for call to 'base::set(char [10], base&)' 32:14: note: candidate is: 11:10: note: void base::set(char, char) 11:10: note: no known conversion for argument 2 from 'base' to 'char'

Comment: There are too many errors to fix. Use `std:string` instead of raw char arrays, this would make many things easier.

Comment: The function doesn't take 2 strings. It takes 2 chars. The intent of your code isn't clear, so it's difficult to suggest a fix. Do you want pass strings or chars?

Comment: I want to pass two string and then print both of them together.

Comment: Ex.- First string Paul
Second string Roony
then print Paul Roony

Answer (score 1):

Given your comment, your intent has been clarified. You need to pass either char pointers or `std::string`s to your `set` method. `char` is just a single char, not a string of chars.

The following will do what you want.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::string;

class base
{
    public:
    string s, r;

    void set(const string& a, const string& b)
    {
        s = a;
        r = b;
    }

    void show()
    {
        cout << s << ' ' << r << '\n';
    }
};

int main()
{
    string first, second;

    cout << "Enter first string\n";
    cin >> first;

    cout << "Enter second string\n";
    cin >> second;

    base b;
    b.set(first, second);
    b.show();
}
```